# Setw and setfill equivalent in BASH

Tags: bash, setw

Could you please tell me what the equivalent BASH code for the following C++ snippet would be:

```
std::cout << std::setfill('x') << std::setw(7) << 250;
```

The output is:

```
xxxx250
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on Linux, it has a `printf` program for just this purpose. Other UNIX variants may also have it.

Padding a numeric with `x` is not really on of its use cases but you could get the same result with:

```
pax> printf "%7d\n" 250 | tr ' ' 'x'
xxxx250
```

That outputs the 250 with space padding, then uses the `tr` translate utility to turn those spaces into `x` characters.

If you're looking for a `bash`-only solution, you can start with:

```
pax> n=250 ; echo ${n}
250

pax> n=xxxxxxx${n} ; echo ${n}
xxxxxxx250

pax> n=${n: -7} ; echo ${n}
xxxx250
```

---

If you want a generalised solution, you can use this function `fmt`, unit test code is included:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# fmt <string> <direction> <fillchar> <size>
# Formats a string by padding it to a specific size.
# <string> is the string you want formatted.
# <direction> is where you want the padding (l/L is left,
#    r/R and everything else is right).
# <fillchar> is the character or string to fill with.
# <size> is the desired size.
#
fmt()
{
    string="$1"
    direction=$2
    fillchar="$3"
    size=$4
    if [[ "${direction}" == "l" || "${direction}" == "L" ]] ; then
        while [[ ${#string} -lt ${size} ]] ; do
            string="${fillchar}${string}"
        done
        string="${string: -${size}}"
    else
        while [[ ${#string} -lt ${size} ]] ; do
            string="${string}${fillchar}"
        done
        string="${string:0:${size}}"
    fi
    echo "${string}"
}
```

```
# Unit test code.

echo "[$(fmt 'Hello there' r ' ' 20)]"
echo "[$(fmt 'Hello there' r ' ' 5)]"
echo "[$(fmt 'Hello there' l ' ' 20)]"
echo "[$(fmt 'Hello there' l ' ' 5)]"
echo "[$(fmt 'Hello there' r '_' 20)]"
echo "[$(fmt 'Hello there' r ' .' 20)]"
echo "[$(fmt 250 l 'x' 7)]"
```

This outputs:

```
[Hello there         ]
[Hello]
[         Hello there]
[there]
[Hello there_________]
[Hello there . . . . ]
[xxxx250]
```

and you're not limited to just printing them, you can also save the variables for later with a line such as:

```
formattedString="$(fmt 'Hello there' r ' ' 20)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print padding like this:

```
printf "x%.0s" {1..4}; printf "%d\n" 250
```

If you want to generalize that, unfortunately you'll have to use `eval`:

```
value=250
padchar="x"
padcount=$((7 - ${#value}))
pad=$(eval echo {1..$padcount})
printf "$padchar%.0s" $pad; printf "%d\n" $value
```

You can use variables directly in brace sequence expressions in ksh, but not Bash.

Answer (score -1):

```
s=$(for i in 1 2 3 4; do printf "x"; done;printf "250")
echo $s
```